# Is RegEx Pattern Matcher.find() case sensitive?

Tags: java, regex

Is matcher.find() case sensitive ? How can i do a case in-sensitive check for the input string with this defined pattern ?

```
java.util.regex.Pattern ptn = (?s)\\00|<|\\+ADw-|>|\\+AD4-|%[0-9a-f]{2}|System[.][a-z]|javascript\\s*:|\\?.*:|\\(\\s*[a-z]{2,}\\.[a-z]{2,}.*\\)
java.util.regex.Matcher matcher = ptn.matcher(inputString);
if(matcher.find())
{
    //Yes, input string matches the RegEx
}
```

***Example***:

+ADw- matches
+Adw  does not matches

***I want both these text to match this pattern. How can i achieve that ?***

Comment: `?i` makes the regex *case-insensitive* . Although that question is under *ruby*, the same rules apply to *java* as well  :)

Comment: i tried adding a ?i to the end of my RegEx pattern and tested here https://regex101.com/  but still it is case sensitive. Where exactly should the ?i be mentioned ?

Comment: i prefixed the regEx pattern with (?)  and it worked. Thank you very much.